# Google Calendar Add On is not opening the authorization URL

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, clasp

I have created a Google Calendar Add On and everything is functioning 100% except for when it comes time for the user to Login to my OAuth service after they have authorized the scopes from Google.

[image]

So if a user needs to authenticate with my OAuth service, I use the following code:

```
if (!auth) {
    return ConferenceDataService.newConferenceDataBuilder().setError(ConferenceDataService.newConferenceError().setConferenceErrorType(ConferenceDataService.ConferenceErrorType.AUTHENTICATION).setAuthenticationUrl(WROAuth.generateAuthorizationUrl())).build();
  }
```

There are no errors in the logs nor console at this point and when I inspect the network calls in the developer console I can see the `CreateConferenceData` API getting called which returns the correct authorization URL:

[image]

The issue is that the popup to open my auth flow is not appearing. If I manually visit the authorization URL, I am presented with my auth screen and I can successfully follow the auth flow and everything functions 100%. But there is no way to get the calendar to trigger the popup.

I have tried multiple browsers in Private tabs and without. There are no popup blockers getting triggered. The flow basically just stops with the message on screen with "Failed to create conference. Try again"

This issue is only replicated on some user accounts and not all, so it seems like an inconsistency but I am not entirely sure what could be the reason. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue for our GCal addon and raised a Google Workspace ticket for the same. It was a bug on Google's end and has been resolved now.